# Wordpress User link submits

Tags: wordpress, form-submit, registration, profile

So thing i want to do is: to have a submit field on a page where user can submit a link and after succesful submition user will be redirected to register page and after succsesful registration link he submited earlier will appear on his profile. How is this possible? any plugins that do this maybe? Thans! anything will help!

Answer (score 0):

The flow is like this:

1. Create a custom registration page
2. The page with the link submit form does a `$_POST` to the custom registration page
3. The registration page reads the value of the submitted link from `$_POST` and pre-fills an `<input type="hidden">` field
4. When user submits the registration page, use the `wp_user_create` and the `add_user_meta` functions to set up the profile.

I'd argue that using a plugin is overkill, especially because WP plugins usually aren't very high quality.

**This is barebones example without any validation. Please do not use as is.**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Custom registration
 */

// If the link info is missing, go back to the link submission page
$link = false;
if (!isset($_POST['user_submitted_link']) || !isset($_POST['user_link'])) {
    wp_redirect('/link-submission-page');
} else {
    $link = isset($_POST['user_submitted_link']) ? $_POST['user_submitted_link'] : $_POST['user_link'];
}

// If the registration form was submitted
// the $_POST['user_link'] will be set and we can
// register the user
if (isset($_POST['user_link'])) {
    $new_user = wp_create_user($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email']);
    if ($new_user) {
        add_user_meta($new_user, 'user_link', $_POST['user_link']);
        // User account is created, you can redirect to login or do whatever here
    }
}

// Render the registration form if we have a $link
if ($link) : ?>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_link" value="<?= $_POST['user_submitted_link']; ?>">
        <button>Register</button>
    </form>
<?php endif;
```

So this is a custom page template. Save it as `custom-register.php` or something in your theme folder, then create a new page in WP and use the page template dropdown on the right side to select this "Custom registration" template.

For this to work the link submission page needs to post the value in a field named `user_submitted_link`.

This should be enough to get you started. It's untested code, no guaranties.

Comment: Thanks ! I'v started working on it. Can i ask you aditional questions if i have later?